# Error when installing material-moment-adapter package in angular

Tags: angular, installation, angular-material, package, compatibility

I try run this command in terminal:

```
npm i moment @angular/material-moment-adapter.
```

I got errors:

```
 npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE 
 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree 
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! While resolving: xxxxxxxx-xx@0.0.0 npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@10.2.5 
 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core 
 npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0" from the root project 
 npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: 
 npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@14.1.1 
 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter 
 npm ERR!   @angular/material-moment-adapter@"*" from the root project 
 npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry 
 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps 
 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. 
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! See C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-11T06_40_07_646Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried run `npm install` and `npm i moment` and not working.

(The others "duplicate questions" are not the same situation)

This is package json:

> {
> "name": "certificate-blindess",
> "version": "0.0.0",
> "scripts": {
> "ng": "ng",
> "start": "ng serve",
> "build": "ng build",
> "test": "ng test",
> "lint": "ng lint",
> "e2e": "ng e2e",
> "format": "prettier --write "src/**/*.{ts,html,scss,json}" "!src/**/**migrate**/**/*.*"
> },
> "private": true,
> "dependencies": {
> "@angular/animations": "~10.1.6",
> "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
> "@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
> "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
> "@angular/core": "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0",
> "@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
> "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
> "@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
> "@binssoft/ngx-captcha": "^1.0.0",
> "@types/lodash": "^4.14.162",
> "cors": "^2.8.5",
> "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
> "flatted": "^3.2.4",
> "lodash": "^4.17.20",
> "mat-file-upload": "^11.1.2",
> "ng-recaptcha": "^8.0.1",
> "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
> "prettier": "^2.1.2",
> "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
> "tslib": "^2.0.0",
> "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.7",
> "@angular/cli": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.6",
> "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
> "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
> "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
> "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
> "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
> "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
> "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
> "protractor": "~7.0.0",
> "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
> "tslint": "~6.1.0",
> "typescript": "~4.0.2"
> },
> "peerDependencies": {
> "@angular/core": "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0"
> }
> }

.

Comment: Seems like peer depedencies are causing an issue, try doing `npm install moment --force`, if that works, then you have to lookout which peerdependency is failing'

Comment: There are several errors, this is the first one:peerOptional @angular/animations@"14.1.1" from @angular/platform-browser@14.1.1

Comment: Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

### **Why you get the error**:

You are trying to install a recent version (`14.1.1`) of `@angular/material-moment-adapter` to an Angular project which is on major version `10`.
This causes dependency conflicts because the different Angular packages depend on each other and mostly require the same major version.

You can read this from this error message:

> peer @angular/core@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@14.1.1

It says, that the `@angular/material-moment-adapter` wants `@angular/core` in version `14.x.x` or `15.x.x`.

### **What you can do:**

In your case, I see two possible ways to go:

1. Install an older version of the `@angular/material-moment-adapter` by running:

> npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter@10 moment

2. Upgrade to the major version `14` of all Angular packages (step by step). See [their update guide](https://update.angular.io/) for help.

**Side notes**

1. Your `@angular/core` dependency in the dependencies section of the package.json looks strange:

> "@angular/core": "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0",

With this setup, you basically allow any version between 6.0.0 and the latest 10ish version. But any other version than 10.x.x would cause conflicts with other dependencies. Therefore, I would recommend to use a different version specification here like the one specified for `@angular/common` and so on (= `~10.1.6`).

2. You also got `@angular/core` as peer dependency. This means, that anyone installing your package requires `@angular/core` being installed in any of the versions listed here:

> "@angular/core": "^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0"

If your workspace does not contain a library which should be consumed by other libraries or apps, then you may probably want to delete this `peerDependencies` entry.